# Access each pixel of an image with parallel.for using

Tags: c#, image, asynchronous, parallel-processing, pixel

So, I am working on a C# project that should copy an image pixel by pixel into another image variable. I wrote the code and it works correctly, but it is a little bit too slow. Now I am trying to make the code work asynchronously with Parallel.For, but I am struggling with locking the variables which are changed in the loop and it always throws an exception.

So, that is my initial code (I know in this way the program doesn't make much sense, but it is just a simple example) :

```
Bitmap loadedImage = new Bitmap(filename);
var newImage = new Bitmap(loadedImage.Width, loadedImage.Height);

Color color = new Color();
byte r, g, b;

for (int i = 0; i < loadedImage.Height; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < loadedImage.Width; j++)
    {
        color = loadedImage.GetPixel(j, i);
        r = color.R;
        g = color.G;
        b = color.B;

        newImage.SetPixel(j, i, Color.FromArgb(r, g, b));
    }
}
```

I would really appreciate it if someone helps me with making the program work asynchronously.

Comment: Please post what you have tried that didn't work.

Comment: I had written something like the code below in the first answer and the exception was InvalidOperationException with this message: Object is currently in use elsewhere.

Comment: Why do you want to copy the bitmap pixel by pixel? Do you want to apply some transformations or something? Just copying the image is far easier and faster with `Graphics.DrawImage`.

Comment: Yes, I want to apply a lot of different operations with this image after I find the best solutions to some of these simple performance issues, such as accessing pixels.

Answer (score 0):

Basically for a parallel for your data set should be sufficiently large -- otherwise the added cost of context switching will make things slower, not faster.

Also, lockbits will make things much faster than you'll get with GetPixel.

That said, the implementation is pretty easy:

```
Bitmap loadedImage = new Bitmap(filename); 
var newImage = new Bitmap(loadedImage.Width, loadedImage.Height);

// don't create variables here...
Parallel.For(0, loadedImage.Height, (i) =>
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < loadedImage.Width; j++)
        {
            // but here -- that's better for a lot of reasons.

            var color = loadedImage.GetPixel(j, i);
            var r = color.R;
            var g = color.G;
            var b = color.B;

            newImage.SetPixel(j, i, Color.FromArgb(r, g, b));                    
        }
    });
```

As long as there is no overlap in data, this will work. In my case there isn't.

PS: i've been working with processing photo's and `Parallel.For` in the past and found that in most cases it'll just slow things down instead of making it faster. Lockbits and unsafe code is *really* the way to go.

Comment: Thanks for the comment :), but when I try your code, it throws an exception again.

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Object is currently in use elsewhere.

Comment: Ah right, that probably means that you can only use an image non-concurrently. Or in blunt terms: No `Parallel.For` for you my friend. Lockbits is really your only way to go from here forward...

Comment: OK thanks a lot :) But does it mean that I should use the Lockbits method in other cases, such as changing pixels, resizing, etc.?

Comment: Either LockBits or Graphics. Yes.

Comment: @ДимитърГ. I assume you have the bitmap assigned to some `PictureBox` or some other GUI element - you must not modify GUI from threads other than the GUI thread. If not, it's probably that `SetPixel` and `GetPixel` internally lock the `Bitmap` - there really isn't a way to parallelize what you're doing with Set/GetPixel. You need to use `Lockbits` (which is going to be much faster even if not parallelized anyway).

Comment: The problem with `Parallel.For` is that it really isn't designed for iterations like this - it only works well when the loop body takes a significant amount of time. You'll have to use your own partitioner to get decent performance from this - or you could use `AsParallel`, which doesn't seem to have this issue.

Comment: @Luaan Yea... I've actually tested that - even with a custom partitioner on big photo's I haven't beaten a simple loop for most operations... Still, the OP asked...

Comment: Yes, in this case it doesn't take so much time, but when it comes to cases when I have to move through each pixel, such as removing or changing colors, adding different effects, resizing, etc. , it takes a while. And I was just wondering if it is possible to improve the performance using parallel loops instead of normal ones.